# Do a android/ios apps need to use apple or googles in-app purchase API if product is part hardware part subscription?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, in-app-purchase

We are developing a free app, but want to allow for the user to purchase a hardware obd-II dongle in-app that has a data subscription packaged together (so say $99 per month for the dongle and $20 a month for the data connection).   I know you can't use in-app payment/billing API's for hardware, but what about the data connection is it ok to not use the API since it's part of the bundle?

All articles I have researched only define how single items should be handled, not a combined purchase like this.

Comment: It's really a matter of store policies and how stringent their review is. Google doesn't care. Apple cares, but if you're not too blatant while advertising outside payments, they might let it slip.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, no, it is not.  You might call it a bundle, but you still have two products, a piece of hardware, and a data plan which is electronically delivered merchandise.  When I buy my phone, I may pay Apple over time for the hardware, but I separately have to get a data plan.  I'm sure they would say the same thing about your hardware.  So, my guess is that you would have to bill your hardware subscription outside of Apple's in-app purchase API and you would have to bill your data plan through the in-app API as it falls under the classification of what they want a 30% cut of.

But, if you are not selling the dongle or the data plan through your app, and not utilizing the data plan through your app, then I think you wouldn't have to use the in-app purchase API.

The key is whether the electronically delivered merchandise enhances the functionality of your app, and if so, then they want to control it.